# OpenMP Critical Section Implementation

Tags: openmp, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

Currently I am doing research about different implementations to achieve Mutual exclusion.

As part of my research I want to include some information about the implementation of the `critical section` within `OpenMP`.  
However, I cannot find any documentation about this; does anyone knows how `OpenMP` achieves `Critical Sections`? Do you have references for me?

Comment: See, e.g., source code of the GOMP (GNU OpenMP) library. Look for functions `GOMP_critical_start` and `GOMP_critical_end`.

Comment: Or the LLVM libomp http://openmp.llvm.org http://godbolt.org is also useful for looking at the code which the compilers generate for OpenMP constructs.

Comment: @DanielLangr, I found https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgomp/critical.c however, this does not shows me what method is used to do thiis (or is it their implementation). Furthermore, what is the difference between normal OpenMP and GOMP?

Comment: @JimCownie, thanks, I gonna look into that

Comment: @CeesMandjes There is nothing as "normal OpenMP". OpenMP is just a specification of an extension to programming languages. This specification needs to be implemented, typically by compiler vendors. One of such implementations is GNU OpenMP library, which is used by GNU compilers (gcc, g++, gfortran). Other compilers use different OpenMP implementations, such as LLVM libomp, iomp (Intel), etc.

Comment: @DanielLangr : a very minor point... the LLVM OpenMP runtime (libomp) and the Intel OpenMP runtime (libiomp5) are effectively the same. They have the same runtime interface and almost exactly the same codebase (at any point there may be code in one that hasn't yet been propagated to the other, but the aim is for them to be in sync).

Comment: @JimCownie Didn't know that, thanks for clarification.